# SingleInstance and InstancePerRequest not working under Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, asp.net-web-api2

I Have the following registrations:

```
       builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IocContainerMarkerAttribute), false).Any()
                && ((IocContainerMarkerAttribute)t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(IocContainerMarkerAttribute))).IsSingleInstance == false)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest()
            .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);

        builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IocContainerMarkerAttribute), false).Any()
                          && ((IocContainerMarkerAttribute)t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(IocContainerMarkerAttribute))).IsSingleInstance)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .SingleInstance()
            .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
```

And I am trying to request the following dependency:

```
[IocContainerMarker(false)]
public class SecurityProvider : ISecurityProvider
{}
```

Like this:

```
ar authenticationSecurityProvider = (ISecurityProvider)request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(ISecurityProvider));
```

If I comment the second registration build block it works fine but if I uncomment it, I get the following exception:

*No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.*

It seems like a fairly common thing to do, so what am I missing here?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to be another one. I need a singleton dependency to be injected into a InstancePerRequest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I did a mistake and had set a InstancePerRequest dependency in the SingleIntance object.